# What is best way to find count grouped by month in sequalize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Any one can help me to find count of entries grouped by month of createdAt in sequalize module.

I have tried to find on other article to solve this issue. but i could'nt

Thanks in advance

Sequalize script to find module.count({group: ['MONTH(createdAt')]}) but getting the error. how can find the count group by created months

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What was the error?